# Firebase data populated to Listview, how to getKey() of selected Listview item?

Tags: android, firebase, listview

I would like to run getKey() for the item User selected in the listview, so that I can use this key to determine where to take the User, I tried a lot of stackoverflow solutions but failed with many different errors...
Your help will be much appreciated, thank you so much!

Details as below:

1. Firebase data poplulate to Adapter Listview -- No error

   ```
   UserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
   final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
   DatabaseReference gameInfoRef = rootRef.child("user").child(UserId).child("gameInfo");

   gameInfoRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           ListView lv_SelectGame = findViewById(R.id.lv_SelectGame);
           GameList.clear();

           for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               Game game = ds.getValue(Game.class);
               GameList.add(game);
           }

           History_SelectGameAdapter adapter = new History_SelectGameAdapter(ida_History_SelectGame.this, GameList);
           lv_SelectGame.setAdapter(adapter);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           // Getting Post failed, log a message
       }
   });
   ```
2. User clicks Listview item,  return the key (generated by push() previously in other activity, stored in firebase) of that specific game -- Please advise for the solution, thanks!

Firebase Data: (each item in the listview is shown by date)

```
 gameInfo
    -LMIdDTDiUd3ajVVMdzC
          gameDate: "2018-09-01"    
          gameMode: "SomeMode"

    -LMOGEUbCTsaeywPICqi
          gameDate: "2018-09-06"    
          gameMode: "SomeMode"

    -LMQfCQ7TO21WP3qW7v3
          gameDate: "2018-09-15"    
          gameMode: "SomeMode"
```

Now this is the part that I don't know how to wrtie, thanks!

(When I click the Listview item, the Toast is shown without any error, but I have no idea how to get the position and run getKey() based on it)

```
    lv_SelectGame.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            ListView lv_SelectGame = findViewById(R.id.lv_SelectGame);

            Toast.makeText(ida_History_SelectGame.this, "getKey() of this item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the ids like LMIdDTDiUd3ajVVMdzC, LMOGEUbCTsaeywPICqi... ?

Then what you have to do is add a new attribute to your object Game key (if you don't have it).

And when you get the data from Firebase, get the id and add it to the object Game:

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Game game = ds.getValue(Game.class);

            String idYouWant = String.valueOf(ds.getKey());
            //We add to the object game
            game.setKey(idYouWant)

            GameList.add(game);
}
```

Finally you just have to get it from your array GameList, something like this:

```
lv_SelectGame.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            Game game = GameList.get(position);
            String key = game.getKey();
            Toast.makeText(ida_History_SelectGame.this, "getKey() of this item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I encountered "Cannot resolve method getId()" , I guess you mean I should insert a getter and setter for "Id" and "Key" in my Game.class ? @Alex Bean

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the answer, with this: String idYouWant = String.valueOf(ds.getKey()); shouldn't be any error. And yes, getter and setter to have the id with the object game, and you can store all in the Array

Comment: I never known this can be done this way with this logic! Works perfectly, thanks!